# My website shows a white space on the right side, only on mobile

Tags: html, css

My website shows a white space on the right side only on mobile, both firefox and chrome show it just fine, even when using responsive design to simulate mobile size.
I've already tried different solutions, including checking if any of the elements are bigger than the viewport. All the images are 303px by 303px.

```css
$light-blue: #D2D7E8;
$medium-blue: #848CA5;
$dark-blue: #4E5177;
$white: #FFFFFF;

$main-font: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

$side-text-margin: 50px;

@media only screen and (max-width: 734px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        .home{
            .home-background{
                background-color: $light-blue;
                height: 746px;
                width: 100vw;
                .home-center{
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 428px;
                    margin: auto;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    p{
                        text-align: center;
                        font-size: 156px;
                        color: $white;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-family: $main-font;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .experience{
            .experience-background{
                background-color: $dark-blue;
                height: 1384px;
                width: 100vw;
                .experience-center{
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 428px;
                    margin: auto;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    p{
                        font-size: 74px;
                        color: $white;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-family: $main-font;
                    }
                    .images{
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        align-items: center;
                        .experience-image{
                            max-width: 303px;
                            max-height: 303px;
                            size: 20vw 20vw;
                            margin: 40px;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="home">
        <div class="home-background">
            <div class="home-center">
                <p>Paulo Paes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="experience">
        <div class="experience-background">
            <div class="experience-center">
                <p>Experiência</p>
                <div class="images">
                    <img src="Assets\Vortx.png" alt="Logo Vórtx" class="experience-image">
                    <img src="Assets\Lacsed.png" alt="Logo LACSED" class="experience-image">
                    <img src="Assets\Transcolar.png" alt="Logo Transcolar" class="experience-image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, it could be, that there is an overflowing object in your website. Try to add `max-width:100vw;` to the `body` element in your css sheet.

Comment: That didn't work, it still shows the white space. One thing I forgot to mention is that when opening the website on mobile, it loads the page with some zoom, and when I zoom out it shows the white space on the side.